# IndexOutOfBounds Exception when using PDFBox PDFPagePanel

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to use PDFBox's PDFPagePanel to load PDF files into a Swing based eBook reader application.

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(file);
List<PDPage> pages = (List<PDPage>) pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDFPagePanel panel = new PDFPagePanel();
panel.setPage(pages.get(0));
pdfDoc.close();         
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This in theory should work since the PDFPagePanel is just a JPanel and the file being opened appears to be read in properly as I can use the text stripper to extract text fine and get metadata. However whenever I run it, I get the following IndexOutOfBounds exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.seek(RandomAccessBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFileInputStream.read(RandomAccessFileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decompress(FlateFilter.java:161)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decode(FlateFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:295)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.getUnfilteredStream(COSStream.java:172)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.<init>(PDFStreamParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:251)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:125)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PDFPagePanel.paint(PDFPagePanel.java:98)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The page being put into the PDFPagePanel (pages.get(0)) definitely exists. I get the same error if I try using convertToImage() on a page as well. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `pdfDoc` was closed immediately after `panel.setPage()`. However, `PDFPagePanel` attempts to process the pdf stream only when the page is displayed. To overcome this exception make sure the document is available while it is still in use by `PDFPagePanel`. You may need to make the document a member variable since GC may collect it once the document leaves the scope which will trigger its closing.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you. I do need to add the document as a member variable, but that's fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Aqua thanks for the solution, my problem related to your answer.